# Syntax for OLAP calculated measure based on a dimension

Tags: ssas, olap

Ok, so first off I apologize if this has been answered, but I've searched and after a few hours have given up.  Also, I'm not a developer but rather a curious analyst who's trying to learn.  That said, the short of what I'm trying to do is factor in a dimension filter when creating a calculated measure using OLAP extensions.

So I have a dimension called Call_Workgroup and within that dimension there are different workgroups, such as Sales, SalesSpanish, etc.  What I'm trying to do is calculate Spanish Conversion and have the result in the same table as Total Conversion (with the y-axis as date and the columns would be Total Conversion, Spanish Conversion, etc).  So for Total Conversion, I have the calculation ([Measures].[Orders] / [Measures].[Calls]) and I'd like to add the calculation for Spanish Conversion, ie Spanish Sales / Spanish Calls.  For what it's worth, I'm using OLAP extensions rather than writing MDX queries.  I'm decent with SQL queries, but haven't written any MDX queries yet.

I've tried ([Measures].[Orders],[Call_Workgroup].[CallWorkfroup].&[7] / [Measures].[Calls],[Call_Workgroup].[CallWorkgroup].&[7]) (where 7 is the ID of the Spanish workgroup), but keep getting a syntax error saying "the syntax for "," is incorrect."

So, any guidance?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick introduction to [MDX](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html) and [calcultated members](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/calculated_members.html). I believe your issue is not using the tuple notation (i.e., parenthesis around the members compositing the tuples) :

```
  ( [Measures].[Orders], [Call_Workgroup].[CallWorkfroup].&[7] ) 
/ ( [Measures].[Calls],  [Call_Workgroup].[CallWorkgroup].&[7] )
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Worked like a charm.